# Prettier - Use wildcard

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-scripts, prettier, jsprettier

My current prettier script looks like

```
{
  "prettier": "prettier \"**/*.{js,json,jsx,ts,tsx,md,css,scss,jql,graphql}\""
}
```

and the list of extensions will eventually grow as the prettier support grows...

---

If I try this:

```
{
  "prettier": "prettier \"**/*.*\""
}
```

prettier fails trying to prettify non supported files (e.g. yarn.lock, etc.).

#### Is there any way to use wildcards and let prettier decide whether prettify or skip a file?